# Segmentation Fault from class function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, segmentation-fault

I have a function "printWorld" in a class that prints a 2D array called "world". Whenever I use this function and run my program in the terminal it appears to print the array but then a massive amount of random numbers and at the end says "Segmentation Fault" and closes my program. As soon as I take this function out of my code though everything works just fine.

```
void printWorld()
{
    for(int r = 0; r <= (2*WORLD_SIZE + 1); r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; r <= (2*WORLD_SIZE + 1); c++)
            cout << world[r][c];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This is how the function is written in the class

```
game.printWorld();
```

This is how I'm calling the function.

[This is what is showing in termninal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q8Vg.jpg)

If it helps I have this array initialized all to 0.

Comment: When people use `<=` as the condition in a `for` loop i smell a bug

Comment: What size is your array? Show us the declaration.

Comment: The seg fault is probably because `for(int c = 0; r <= (2*WORLD_SIZE + 1); c++)` is an infinite loop (assuming the condition is true once, since `r` never changes in the scope of that loop). Did you mean `c <= ...`?

Comment: @Imran answered like that below but then deleted the answer. IT is surely the right answer tho

Answer (score 2):

As others have already stated, the mistake is the inner for loop where you compare 'r <= (2*WORLD_SIZE + 1)'

This causes an infinite loop.

Change the inner for loop to be:

```
    for(int c = 0; c <= (2*WORLD_SIZE + 1); c++)
        cout << world[r][c];
    cout << endl;
```

That should do it for you : )